# Can I buy index funds without margin and own it like a stock?

Tags: trading, index-fund, margin, standard-and-poors-500, margin-call

I am a total newbie so this might be a silly question but I am trying to buy S&P 500 and own it like a stock.

The problem is that my broker (XTB) only has the option to buy it with margin and leverage is 1:20. I don't like this because broker can automatically close my position when instrument I bought drops a lot in price and I don't deposit more funds. In this scenario where broker closes my position after a big drop I will obviously lose money which is something I want to avoid.

Ideally I'd like to buy S&P 500 and be able to hold it as long as I want without the need to do backup deposits if the price drops really hard but I don't know if this is possible.

TL;DR - Can I buy S&P 500, e.g. SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust and own it without worrying about margin calls or broker automatically closing?

Comment: I'd check your assumptions on US500 being an index **fund**.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I realised I was mixing up indices and index funds. Edited my original question to avoid any confusions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you'll want to trade an ETF or mutual fund instead of a CFD. See if your broker offers ETFs on that index (I presume the S&P 500) instead of CFDs.  If not, look for a more traditional broker that does.

Or, see if they offer "100% margin" as an option, which just means that you'll have to deposit all of the cash upfront (as you would for an ETF purchase).

Comment: Absolutely. What you're describing is an index fund, whether traditional or ETF.